# Array animation in jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm building array sorting visualization and there is something I can't understand about the animation. I do not know why I have to call **sleep** function right after swapping and doing animation so that everything works.

Also, I have to use await and then **sleep** if I'm doing any function or recursive calls inside the main function. When I do not do any of these, everything turns into a mess.
I'm new to javascript and I've read some about await and async function, but I cannot really get why is this particularly happening.

Is it because await tells us that wait function needs to be executed to complete the program ? Why should I use sleep after swapping?
I want to point to the fact that I did not need to call **sleep** after swapping in other functions like the selection sort one.

Here is heap sort code that contains what is mentioned above:

```
//Sleep
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}


//swapDivs
function swapDivs(big, small) {
    let offbig = $('.slot' + big).offset().left
    let offsmall = $('.slot' + small).offset().left

    $(".slot" + big).animate(
        {
            left: parseFloat($(".slot" + big).css("left").replace("px", "")) - (offbig - offsmall)
        }
        , 500);

    $(".slot" + small).animate(
        {
            left: parseFloat($(".slot" + small).css("left").replace("px", "")) + (offbig - offsmall)
        }
        , 500, function () {
            $('.slot' + small).removeClass('slot' + small).addClass('slot' + big).addClass('temp');
            $('.slot' + big).not('.temp').removeClass('slot' + big).addClass('slot' + small);
            $('.temp').removeClass('temp');
        });

}
// Heap Sort //
async function heapify(main_arr,n,i)
{
    let largest=i,
    lChild=(2*i)+1<n?(2*i)+1:-1,
    rChild=(2*i)+2<n?(2*i)+2:-1;
    $(".slot" + largest).css("background-color", "#f00");
    $(".slot" + lChild).css("background-color", "#ff0");
    $(".slot" + rChild).css("background-color", "#ff0");
    await sleep(800);
    if( lChild < n && main_arr[lChild] > main_arr[largest] )
        {   
            $(".slot" + largest).css("background-color", "#f2f2f2");
            $(".slot" + lChild).css("background-color", "#f00");
            largest=lChild;
        }
        else  $(".slot" + lChild).css("background-color", "#f2f2f2");
        await sleep(800);
        if( rChild<n && main_arr[rChild] > main_arr[largest] )
        {
            $(".slot" + largest).css("background-color", "#f2f2f2");
            $(".slot" + rChild).css("background-color", "#f00");
            largest=rChild;
        }
        else  $(".slot" + rChild).css("background-color", "#f2f2f2");
    
    if(largest!=i)
    {
        swapDivs(largest,i);
        await sleep(800);
        let temp=main_arr[largest];
        main_arr[largest]=main_arr[i];
        main_arr[i]=temp;
        $(".slot" + i).css("background-color", "#f2f2f2");
        await heapify(main_arr,n,largest);
        await sleep(800);
    }
    $(".slot" + largest).css("background-color", "#f2f2f2");
}


async function heapSort(main_arr)
{
    let temp_arr=main_arr.slice();
    for(let i=Math.floor(temp_arr.length/2)-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            await heapify(temp_arr,temp_arr.length,i);
            await sleep(800);
        }


    for (let i=temp_arr.length-1; i>0; i-- )
    {
        $(".slot" + i).css("background-color", "#ff0");
        $(".slot0").css("background-color", "#ff0");
        swapDivs(i,0);
        await sleep(800);
        $(".slot0").css("background-color", "#f2f2f2");
        $(".slot"+i).css("background-color", "#0f0");
        let temp=temp_arr[i];
        temp_arr[i]=temp_arr[0];
        temp_arr[0]=temp;
        await heapify(temp_arr,i,0);
        await sleep(800);
    }
    $(".slot0").css("background-color", "#0f0");
}
```

Comment: I guess the `sleep` function waits for `$().animate` to complete its action(you can find 500ms duration of each animate functions).

Comment: Use CSS to do your animation, using jQuery will use the UI thread, CSS will use the GPU